# TeXLive 2011 ConTeXt problem

Tags: texlive, context

I was wondering if there were any bugs with ConTeXt on TeXLive 2011. I normally do not use ConTeXt but wanted to play with it.

```
$ uname -a
OpenBSD oko.bagdala2.net 5.1 GENERIC.MP#188 i386
```

I have problem processing minimal working example of ConTeXt. The
TeXLive 2011 is the version which is shipped with 5.1

```
$ more test.tex
\setuphead[title][style={\ss\bfd},
    before={\begingroup},
    after={John Doe, the author\smallskip\currentdate\bigskip\endgroup}]

\starttext

\title{\CONTEXT}

\section{Text}
\CONTEXT\ is a document preparation system for the \TEX\ typesetting
program. It offers programmable desktop publishing features and
extensive

\stoptext
```

Output

```
$ texexec test.tex

mtxrun          | kpse fallback with progname 'context' initialized in
0.12 seconds


$ context test.tex

mtxrun          | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
```

It looks like a path problem to me.

**Edit:**

```
$ luatools --generate

mtxrun          | unknown script 'base.lua' or 'mtx-base.lua'
```

However

```
 $ mtxrun --generate
```

"works" but I am getting the same message when trying to compile minimal working example.

However, Joseph Wright's comment is very useful and it seems to imply that ConTeXt problem I encountered is OpenBSD specific. I posted the question at ports.AT.openbsd.org but Edd (our TeXLive maintainer) has not responded yet. I will update the solution.

Comment: The ConTeXt in TL2011 works fine: your example compiles fine for me.

Comment: Try running `mtxrun --generate` as a normal user (or the older syntax: `luatools --generate`; I don't know when the functionality moved from `luatools` to `mtxrun`)

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: @lockstep Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edd Barrett  wrote:

> On Mon, Apr 30, 2012 at 11:02:23PM -0400, Predrag Punosevac wrote:
>
> > $ context test.tex
> >
> > mtxrun          | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
>
> Your example works fine here.
>
> Do you have texlive_texmf-context installed?

I thought I had. However, when I checked manually I had the built package but
not installed. I added it and everything works fine here. Sorry for the
noise.

I also noticed your earlier discussion with Mark and few other
developers about ConTeXt. I support your idea about splitting it from TeXLive completely and making a stand alone port of ConTeXt. Unfortunately due to the nature of my work I have no genuine interest to switch from LaTeX. If Frantisek wants to finish his work I can help testing it. Otherwise I will offer ConTeXt
guys on their mailing list ssh access to one of my OpenBSD machines if
they want to play with it.

Thanks,

Predrag