# ConTeXt under cygwin

Tags: context, cygwin

Since I couldn't use the first-setup.bat script behind my authentication based, HTTP only, corporate proxy, I went for cygwin.

I installed the version 20120628-1 of a package named `texlive-collection-context` and tried it.

```
$ context test.tex

mtxrun          | forcing cache reload
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '/home/xxx/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/bin/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/bin/share/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/bin/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/bin/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/share/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/usr/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/usr/share/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/usr/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '//usr/usr/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '/./texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '/./share/texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '/./share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '/./texmf-site/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | unknown configuration file '/./texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua'
resolvers       | resolving |
resolvers       | resolving | warning: no lua configuration files found
resolvers       | resolving | no texmf paths are defined (using TEXMF)
resolvers       | resolving |
mtxrun          | the resolver databases are not present or outdated
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'mtx-t-contexts.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembered file 'mtx-t-context.lua'
resolvers       | resolving | using suffix based filetype 'lua'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file 'context.lua'
mtxrun          | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
```

However, `texmfcnf.lua` file is available on the system :

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx Domain Users 8356  6 août   2012 /usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua
```

I don't understand why the script try to access `//usr` instead of `/usr`.
In the source of mtxrun, I got stuck in function `identify_configuration_files()` line 12711:

```
local realname = resolvers.resolve(filename)
```

which transform `/selfautodir:/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua` into `//usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua`

And about the last error, it seems that the requested file exists too:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/context/lua/mtx-context.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx Domain Users 65606  2 juil.  2012 /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/context/lua/mtx-context.lua
```

### edit1

A symbolic link from ~/texmf to /usr/share/texmf solve most issues !

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxx Domain Users    16 12 avr.  16:28 texmf -> /usr/share/texmf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxx Domain Users    22 12 avr.  16:36 texmf-dist -> /usr/share/texmf-dist/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 xxx Domain Users    22 12 avr.  16:36 texmf-site -> /usr/share/texmf-site/
```

`$ context test.tex` just hangs (time to timeout each network access) and exit with a new, and very long, error log (even after `mtxrun --generate`):

```
[snip]
resolvers       | resolving | using given filetype 'tex'
resolvers       | expansions | using caches scan of path '/home/a865111/texmf/tex/generic', branch '/home/xxx/texmf/tex/generic'
resolvers       | resolving | remembering file '/home/xxx/.texlive2012/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/74fde8c492a75a0a124aaeb6119048d0/formats/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/context.lus'
resolvers       | formats | unknown stub specification: /home/xxx/.texlive2012/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/74fde8c492a75a0a124aaeb6119048d0/formats/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/context.lus
mtx-context     | error, no format found with name: cont-en, aborting
system          | total runtime: 15.453
```

o_O

### edit2

As in this post : [TeXLive 2011 ConTeXt problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53892/texlive-2011-context-problem)
`texexec test.tex` seems to work now

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: According to the [UNC paths section of the Cygwin User's Guide](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#unc-paths), `//` prefixes have a special meaning in Cygwin (while in regular UNIX, they are equivalent to a single slash).  This could explain the difference you are seeing, but it doesn't explain the behaviour of texmfcnf.lua.

Comment: What happens if you copy the `texmfcnf.lua` file into your home directory?

Comment: OT: Did you try using the [method described on the context wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Proxy_settings_2) for setting the proxy settings for `first-setup.bat`.

Comment: Take a look at the paths David Carlisle reports on chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8950308#8950308 - you might be better off trying to figure out what is going on on chat rather than here.

Comment: OP, did any of the above suggestions help at all?

Comment: I can't answer... time passed, sysadmins changed the rules twice, I gave up to use context at work... for now :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not easily reproducible and OP abandoned the approach.